# How to merge properly into a list of items in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

Lets say I have the following message body:

```xml
<itemsList>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name></name>
    <description></description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>2</id>
    <name></name>
    <description></description>
  </item>
</itemsList>
```

First I will loop through my itemsList by doing the following:

```xml
    <setProperty propertyName="itemsListSize">
      <xpath saxon="true" resultType="java.lang.Integer">count(//*[local-name()='itemsList'])</xpath>
    </setProperty>
    <loop>
      <simple>${exchangeProperty.itemsListSize}</simple>
      <setProperty propertyName="currentId">
        <xpath saxon="true" resultType="java.lang.String">
           //*[local-name()='itemsList'][function:simple('${exchangeProperty.CamelLoopIndex}')+1]/*[local-name()='id']/text()
        </xpath>
      </setProperty>
      <enrich strategyRef="someAggregationStrategy">
        <constant>direct:getItemInfoById</constant>
      </enrich>
    </loop>
```

In the example above "getItemInfoById" will be a route that uses currentId property and calls a service that will return something like:

```xml
<customItem>
  <customId>1</customId>
  <customName>John</customName>
  <customDescription>Human</customDescription>
</customItem>
```

And I want my end result for each loop to enrich my initial message by mapping customName into name and customDescription into description of my current loop item.
Do I achieve it by using some sort of AggregationStrategy in the enrich node? And if so, what would that look like?

For reference this is my current Aggregation Strategy:

```java
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {

        for (Entry<String, Object> e : resource.getProperties().entrySet()) {
            String k = e.getKey();
            Object v = e.getValue();
            original.setProperty(k, v);
        }

        original.getOut().setBody(original.getIn().getBody());
        return original;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use JacksonXml dataformat to marshall the message body to a java object :

```xml
<dataFormats>
    <jacksonXml id="xmlDataFormat" unmarshalType="foo.bar.ItemsList"/>
</dataFormats>
```

Instead of the loop logic, you would just need to do this:

```xml
<from uri="direct:input"/>
<unmarshal><custom ref="xmlDataFormat"/></unmarshal>
<enrich strategyRef="someAggregationStrategy">
   <constant>direct:getItemInfoById</constant>
</enrich>
```

You "direct:getItemInfoById" route would return a list of CustomItem.

Your aggregation strategy would be simpler :

```java
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange original, Exchange resource) {

        var customItems = resource.getMessage().getBody(CustomItems.class);

        var itemsList = original.getMessage().getBody(ItemsList.class);

        // Here, your code to merge each element in itemsList with its matching item in customItems
}
```

If you need to still have an xml message at the end of your camel route, you just need to marshall your object after the "enrich" step:

```xml
<from uri="direct:input"/>
<unmarshal><custom ref="xmlDataFormat"/></unmarshal>
<enrich strategyRef="someAggregationStrategy">
   <constant>direct:getItemInfoById</constant>
</enrich>
<marshall><custom ref="xmlDataFormat"/></marshal>
```